# Inverse Laplace Transform of a complicated function

Tags: laplace-transform

Help with finding the inverse Laplace Transform of

$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{M^{2}-s^{2}}}e^{\frac{\sqrt{N^{2}-s^{2}}}{s}}$$

Comment: Could we have some text with that ?
Like what you want, what you've tried ?